# Spacer between panels in jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a small requirement that has eluded me...

Using jQuery Accordion (version 1.10.2)

Is there a way to put a spacer between the sections of the accordion?

Basically what the owner wants is the default functionality of the accordion as it is, but they want some space between the sections vertically.

Can this be accomplished?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a top margin to the accordion sections except the first like this

```
  #accordion > h3 {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  #accordion > h3:first-child {
      margin-top: 0;
  }
```

[Updated example](http://jsbin.com/uxefup/3/edit) using the html structure on jquery ui docs

Comment: Very close, thank you....  but when the accordian collapses with movement to the top of the form, the panels are still stacked...   anyway to keep 25px between the entire panels - collapsed?