# jQuery Accordian padding in content area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Using jQuery version 1.10.2 accordian

I am using the sample from the website as my template - but the content area within the panels has such a large space on all four sides of the inner panel....

I need to reclaim some of that space - how can i reclaim some of the space on the left, right, top and bottom of the panel?

thank you

ITS NOT THE SAME QUESTION - 
This question is working WITHIN the panel...  the previous question was space BETWEEN the accordian panels.

you people that marked the questions as answered and duplicate are NOT READING THE QUESTION.

Comment: How is this different from the last question you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503038/spacer-between-panels-in-jquery-accordion?

Comment: wow - because now i am working INSIDE the panels themselves.

Comment: Based on your last question and this one, you may find it helpful to review various [CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference). Inner spacing is usually defined by an elements [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/padding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation, under [theming](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#theming), you will see the HTML that is created by the jQuery Accordion.  The content of each section uses the class `ui-accordion-content`.

You can modify this class in your own stylesheet to change the [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/padding)